# we access other's PC in network through putty tool, Is it possible the same using commands (CML)?

Tags: command-line, ssh, network-bridge, putty

In putty tool, We access others PC by setting the **session-> logging** and **ssh-> tunnel** settings with appropriate IP, dynamic port number, etc.But here, I need help regarding how to set these ssh tunnel details Destination: dynamic, IPv4 and source port is 8080 through command line.

Help me to access others pc using ssh through command line with dynamic settings as arguments to putty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the settings with unique session name in putty tool once per IP, then use this command to connect
`#putty -load <session_name> -l <pc_loginid> -pw <password>`

Answer (score 1):

putty is a windows program. I know people running it under [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) but this is still a GUI program and not a command-line (i.e. terminal-based) one.

You could use [ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo). To specify the port use option `-p`:

```
ssh -p 8080 user@host
```

Comment: putty tool is well developed for linux also. In ubuntu, we can use without wine.

Comment: Oops, apologies, didn't know about that.  Will give it a try.